# I need a Regex Expression for searching title

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

In a dataset, I need to find how many instances of "mr.","mrs." and "miss." there are. For example:

```
Obama, Mr. Barack Hussein
Obama, Mrs. Michelle LaVaughn Robinson
Biden, Mr. Joe
Portman, Miss. Natalie
```

In this expression, it must search after "," and must get "Mr." exactly. In my search code, it also counts "mrs" instead of only "Mr.".

```
Mr = df.loc[df['Name'].str.contains('Mr.', case=False)]
```

Comment: Can you guarantee that the text format is always "lastname, honorific firstname(s)"?

Comment: i guarantee that the format is surname, title. but in my code it scans all name, not after ",". i need to find a way to search after ","

Comment: Try a regex of `\w, +(Mrs\.) .+` or `\w, +(Mrs\.) \w+( \w+)*`, for "Mrs.". Obviously, modify to count Mr, Miss, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex. The titles are distinctive enough that they should not appear anywhere else.

```
df['Name'].str.extract('(Mr\.|Mrs\.|Miss\.)').value_counts()
```

output:

```
Mr.      2
Miss.    1
Mrs.     1
```